# System date is displaying when the value is NULL in date field in SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Below is my SQL query used in SSRS report

```
SELECT Claimname,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ClaimResponsedate,101) FROM Claim WHERE DataSourceID = 100011
```

From the above query 'ClaimResponsedate' may get NULL values but in SSRS report for this field displaying 1/1/1990 when the value comes as NULL.

I need to display empty value in report if the date value is NULL.

I tried below code to avoid but it is not working

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ClaimResponsedate.Value),"",Fields!ClaimResponsedate.Value)
OR
=IIF(Len(Fields!ClaimResponsedate)=0,"",Fields!ClaimResponsedate.value)
```

So please help me to achieve this i.e. display empty value in report if the date value is NULL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL to be:

```
SELECT Claimname,
    CASE WHEN ClaimResponseDate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,ClaimResponsedate,101) END as [ClaimResponseDate]
 FROM Claim WHERE DataSourceID = 100011
```

---

The other option is to change your report field to be the following:

```
=Replace(Fields!ClaimResponsedate.Value,"1/1/1900","")
```

Comment: Yes i tried this scenario also even though in the report it is displaying 1/1/1900..

So please advice me to achieve

Comment: @VinnaKanna: Update with alternative solution

Comment: Would "WHEN ClaimResponseDate IS NULL THEN ''" not be a better choice for your first solution?

Comment: @Frank - yeah I guess that would be better.

Comment: But if really the claim has 1/1/1990 then we will loose the data correct?
Is there any another approach to solve this